# Step through each instruction in Geany

Tags: debugging, geany

Using the Geany IDE, is it possible to step through each instruction in a function, as each instruction is being run? I know that many IDEs (including Eclipse and Visual Studio) have this feature, but I haven't yet found it in Geany.

```
function doStuff(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        console.log("Is it possible to step through this JavaScript function in Geany?");
    }
}
doStuff();
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Linux, Windows or MacOS?

Comment: @moebius_eye I'm using Windows now.

Comment: You should check if the gdb plugin works on windows. I would seriously doubt it though.

Answer (score 2):

The older GDB plugins (Geany-GDB & Debugger) do not support Windows due to their dependency on the non-cross-platform libvte, but the latest one named [Scope](https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/blob/master/scope/README) is supposed to work on Windows (at least according to that README). I know the author frequently works on Windows so it's more than likely the case, but it will obviously not have the nice built-in terminal emulator that would get on *nix with that plugin.